# How to do activity transtion?

Tags: android

I have implemented one App which has many activities.. . I want to implement one activity as left and right and vice versa in fling transition manner between whole activity. For example

SO when you hit next there should be transition between next activity and when you hit previous there should be transition between previous . How should i Implement this?. ... Its fling  but not with touch, but using those buttons...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) (video demo [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZTiJmclaRc)), [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), or [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Define translation animations in xml then use `overridePendingTransition` BEFORE setContentView in each Activity. E.g. `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slidein, R.anim.slideout);` You probably need to put this in onResume if you want it to work both ways (i.e. when you're going from and back to that Activity.).

Comment: Thanks for reply it really helped..... I just wanna know I made transition successfully .. but have simple problem...what i am doing is, i get the data from the database and store it in cursor and  i show it to user via activity..my problem is since i am using same activity to do the transition it will get the data from databse everytime..